# Finding a sequence that has at least 3 partial limits.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This was a question on a real analysis final exam.

Define a sequence $ a_n $ such that $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\big(a_na_{n+1}) = 1 $, and has at least three partial limits.

In fact, there was a different wording for this:
Prove/disprove that all sequences $a_n$ that satisfy $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\big(a_na_{n+1}) = 1 $, have at most 2 partial limits.

I had no idea how to approach that problem, and the solution is not intuitive (for me, I guess).

Comment: The first formulation "define a sequence ... " is misleading when you see the second one...

Answer (score 1):

$a_{n+1}$ is determined from $a_n$ (at least asymptotically), since $\lim(a_n a_{n+1}) = 1$. In other words, $a_{n+1} = 1/a_n$ asymptotically. If $\lim_{n\, odd}a_n = x$ it must be that $\lim_{n\, even} = 1/x$. Assume by contradiction that you have (more than) 3 different partial limits. Do you see the issue / contradiction?